# Setting file name encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I have an input file in a defined encoding (utf8) from which I create different files whose names and content (again utf8) are taken form that input file.

My problem is that one a particular windows system, the files created do not have the correct characters. The content of these files is perfectly readable, but their names not.
Instead of `Ü.xml`, the file has the name `├£.xml`.

On other Windows systems everything works fine.

The file content's encoding can be set in `OutputStreamWriter`'s second argument, but the file name's encoding can not be set in `new File(name)` is seems.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you manually copy `Ü.xml` to that windows system? What's the default encoding of the JVMs on both systems?

Comment: Copying manually works. `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` is "Cp1252" on both.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It turns out the issue is a maven issue, as the files are correctly generated by the java execution, but only when maven packages them into a jar, the problem is there. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258347/file-name-encoding-in-jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing two chars where there should be one UTF-8 multi-byte char `ü`. that Windows does not seem to have UTF-8 as file encoding. And a UTF-8 file was copied onto that system, like unpacking a zip file.

`System.getProperty("file.encoding")` should give the platform encoding. Maybe, remotely imaginable, it is some odd case not covered by Java resp. Windows, like a compressed directory, or a second external disk formatted with a non-UTF-8 capable file system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. file.encoding is "Cp1252" on both systems.

Comment: How was the file created? Manually should have no fault. In Java, as `"ü.xml"` there could be two errors: the source encoding can be set in the IDE, and the compiler can be parametrized with the encoding too: `javac -encoding Cp1252 ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses the "platform's default charset" to convert file names to strings, and there's no way to change that behaviour through the standard API. You *may*, on *some* systems, be able to change the default encoding when you launch the JVM:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=cp1252 package.ClassName
```

On other systems the only way to affect the file name encoding is through the system locale settings. You can read more about that here: http://jonisalonen.com/2012/java-and-file-names-with-invalid-characters/