# File name encoding in jar

Tags: maven, encoding

My maven run creates different files in the target directory and compresses them into the jar file.

In case special characters like an `Ü` exist in the **file names**, the file names in the jar archive are not correctly encoded and showed as `├£`. (The file contents are not affected)

As the files are correctly shown in the target directory, the issue must be caused by maven's jar:jar.

The interesting thing is that if I use the unzip command in Linux, the files are extracted with correct name, if I use Windows Explorer or 7zip in Windows, the names are not correct.

Comment: Do you have project.build.sourceEncoding property specified in POM?

Comment: I already tried to set is but it did not change anything here

Comment: Same issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343367/maven-changes-filenames-encoding-errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and upgrading my maven-war-plugin version solved the problem I think you should do the same with your maven jar plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```