# Java File.listFiles() returns files that do 'not exist' according to `exists()`

Tags: java, file, encoding

I noticed this problem in our productive code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /somePath/�.png does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.sizeOf(FileUtils.java:2413)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(FileUtils.java:2479)
```

The underlying cause is this:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileNameTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File[] files = new File("/somePath").listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            System.out.println(file + " - " + (file.exists() ? "exists" : "missing!!"));
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0.png - exists
7.png - exists
4.png - exists
8.png - exists
1.png - exists
3.png - exists
�.png - missing!!
2.png - exists
5.png - exists
�.png - missing!!
6.png - exists
d.png - exists
$.png - exists
s.png - exists
+.png - exists
9.png - exists
```

The "missing" files are named with the symbols ["µ" (Mu)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)) and ["€" (Euro)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign).

It also seems to be the case that these filename use the wrong encoding.
When i list the files in bash they show up wrong as well.
When i convert the output of `ls` from latin1 to UTF-8 they appear correctly (at least mu).

But nevertheless ...

1. these files exist
2. file.listFiles() lists them
3. for the 2 special cases: file.exists() returns false

I believe this is a bug in the JVM. Can anybody confirm this?

Is there already a bug-report? Any ideas how to fix this? (Renaming the files is not an option as they are user generated and might re-appear in any form or shape.)

My System:

- Ubuntu 4.2.0
- java version "1.8.0_102"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
- Apache Commons IO 2.4

Comment: what is the value of the **file.encoding** property ? _System.getProperty("file.encoding")_

Comment: `file.encoding: UTF-8`

Comment: is there something similar for the filesystem?

Comment: on linux , the file names are stored without a specific encoding. therefore you must somehow somewhere define what encoding your file names are. one possibility is using **file.encoding** in JVM. you mentioned that your file names do not show properly when converted to UTF-8 , therefore your example will always fail. in this example,you must choose the correct encoding that works with all your files.

Comment: the question mark symbol represents an unconvertable character and will always be different than the real file name.

Comment: this behaviour is not a bug , it is a consequence of the missing filename encoding information inside the filesystem, or the interface Java chose to use to be the most compatible.

Comment: So essentially Java converts any unconvertable character into the questionmark-symbol. Thus the resulting filename does not correspond to the actual filename on the HDD anymore and thus can not be found ... *sigh* ok thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a consequence of missing encoding information in the filesystem. 
Java has no way of representing the file name correctly, because it does not know the encoding. Therefore the file is inaccessible from Java without specifying the correct encoding.

The simplest way to solve this is to set the **file.encoding** property correctly, and use that encoding in all your file names.

**EDIT:** i found an article that shows another possible behaviour, maybe changing the **file.encoding** does not help. Better test it if you want to use something else than UTF-8 . http://jonisalonen.com/2012/java-and-file-names-with-invalid-characters/

i also found maybe a relevant discussion: [Setting file name encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196950/setting-file-name-encoding)

Comment: Thanks. I finally used `convmv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8 -r .` to convert all "broken" files. The problem is now gone.

Comment: On a related note, Unix filenames, although apparently text strings, are really just byte sequences for which three byte values (NUL, /, .) have special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but how to detect those files without `File#exists`.

The file name stems from a file name on disk with a wrong encoding (instead of UTF-8). It gives a Unicode placehold U+FFFC `�` instead of the wrong byte.

You might assume that nobody will name hishers file name with an U+FFFC. So:

```
String name = file.getName();
if (name.contains("\uFFFC")) {
    String namePattern := name.replace(".", "\\.").replace("\uFFFC", ".");
    ... file is problematic
}
```

In every case you probably have to correct the file calling ProcessBuilder with a pattern rename.

> It just might be that reading the directory as file with encoding CP1252 (Windows Latin-1) just might get the correct file name.

> Or who knows, the new Files & Path methods like directory walks might show some improvement. Which I doubt. Though a charset converter could do give the offending byte.